# Get Shared channel list and joined user list via slack API

Tags: jq

My goal is to list up Slack shared channel list, which joined users via Slack web API.

```
 /usr/bin/curl -s -XPOST 'https://slack.com/api/conversations.list?token=MY_TOKEN&pretty=1' | jq -r '.channels[]|select(.is_shared = "true")'
```

But return is including non-shared channels also, like a `(.is_shared = "false")`. I have no idea why am I getting such results. Appreciate any help.

I use following code

```
/usr/bin/curl -s -XPOST 'https://slack.com/api/conversations.list?token=MY_TOKEN&pretty=1'
```

and  results is

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "channels": [
        {
            "id": "C2U56FH6Z",
            "name": "hoge_general",
            "is_channel": true,
            "is_group": false,
            "is_im": false,
            "created": 1477470814,
            "is_archived": false,
            "is_general": false,
            "unlinked": 0,
            "name_normalized": "hoge_general",
            "is_shared": false,
            "parent_conversation": null,
            "creator": "U2UABCDEF",
            "is_ext_shared": false,
            "is_org_shared": false,
            "shared_team_ids": [
                "T2U94ABCDE"
            ],
            "pending_shared": [],
            "pending_connected_team_ids": [],
            "is_pending_ext_shared": false,
            "is_member": true,
            "is_private": false,
            "is_mpim": false,
            "topic": {
                "value": "Editor \2",
                "creator": "U2UABCDE",
                "last_set": 1478675694
            },
            "purpose": {
                "value": "AAA editor ",
                "creator": "U2UABABCDF",
                "last_set": 14774596815
            },
            "previous_names": [],
            "num_members": 11
        },
```

So, I try to get channnel name which method is .

Comment: I think you missed the equality check and instead added an assignment operation. It should have been `select(.is_shared == "true")`

Comment: Thanks Inian.
You may be right. I use "==" instead of "=" .
But return is none.

I have surely shared channel on Slack but Web API conversations.list does not return shared channel list.

Comment: We need to see the JSON that you are trying this on. Without that, we can't really suggest the right filter to use (or) what is wrong with yours

Answer (score 0):

Comparison of values in jq is done using the `==` operator; `=` is the assignment operator which changes values (similar to many C-like programming languages).

The `is_shared` property in your JSON document is of type boolean (`true` or `false`), but you are comparing it to a string (`"true"` or `"false"`). That will always result in false (`true == "true"` is false).

Instead, compare booleans with booleans: `.channels[] | select(.is_shared == true)`

And, as with most other programming languages, conditionals compare implicitly against true, so if you have `== true` somewhere, this is redundant 99% of the time and can be simplified: `.channels[] | select(.is_shared)`